# LAMP: Apache not accepting "index.php" files and displaying directory listing

Tags: apache2, php, lamp

I just installed lamp here on my desktop. i am using 12.04. Installation works perfectly but when i tried to access localhost/wordpress/ it doest read the index.php. It shows like this:
[image]

Why is it happening? why my localhost doesnt read the index.php? I tried to create a dir and put an index.php there but again it shows the whole listing of directory and ignore my index.php. Please help. Thank you

Comment: If you click on the index.php file does it display your wordpress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a directive to your apache2 configuration or your .htaccess file. Like this...

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

...otherwise, it just defaults to index.html

Same thing if you wanted index.shtml, you'd need:

```
DirectoryIndex index.shtml
```

Comment: Where is the location on .htaccess file is?

Comment: Usually below the directory where your .html files are kept. There are directives to set this as well. Some Googling for apache2 configuration will help with this.

Answer (score 0):

changing the public_html folder's/htdocs folder permissions to `755` will solve this problem. I suddenly changed the permissions of my blog and this happened with me. I have searched a lot but in vain. Finally I got it and solved this issue.